# Python: Caching and Streaming Large Remote Files

Tags: python, asynchronous, web, caching, stream

I am setting up a web server to cache large remote files for multiple machines on a LAN. For instance, there is a file at `https://example.com/path/to/large/file.zip` that is frequently accessed and should be cached.

When a client requests the file at `https://**myserver.com**/path/to/large/file.zip`, I want the server to check if the file is cached. If it is, the cached version could be sent immediately; if not, the server should download the file to disk and send it to the client.

However, if the file is 2GB and my bandwidth is only 10MB/s, I don't want the first client to wait for the entire download to complete. Instead, I want the client to receive a copy of the file as it is being downloaded by the cache server. That is to say, caching and **streaming at the same time**.

Is it possible to implement this in a Python web framework? Async framework like aiohttp would be preferable.